# why uses [static final] in android?

Tags: java, android

I am a fresher in Android.
Recently I read a lot source code about Android.
I really do not understand these codes below.

```
public DemoActivity {
     private static final String TAG = "DemoActivity";

   //.........
}
```

Why uses **static**?

Comment: You are missing the data type `private static final String TAG = "DemoActivity"`

Comment: Do you know what `static` mean? If yes then what is confusing you here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is way too basic. Anyone with notions of this technology would not find this useful.

Comment: While I agree this question should be closed, being _basic_ does not inherently make a question bad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly does "static" mean when declaring "global" variables in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415781/what-exactly-does-static-mean-when-declaring-global-variables-in-java)

Comment: @Pshemo - I think the question should be why `static final`? :)

Answer (score 5):

You use static in this case because the String named `TAG` is associated with the `DemoActivity` class itself, not with any particular instance of `DemoActivity`. In this case it is a constant referring to the name of the class, this is the same for any instance of class `DemoActivity`, and so is `static`.

Answer (score 1):

`static final String TAG = "DemoActivity"` ==> This will make the string literal `"DemoActivity"` a *compile-time* constant i.e, everywhere you use `TAG` in your code, it will be replaced by the value `"DemoActivity"` during compilation. i.e, in Bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when we create tag we declare it like

```
public final static String TAG = "APPLICATION_TAG";
```

1. the sole purpose of using static is to make variable exist in memory
   as long as Parent lifetime is there
2. other use is so you can use this tag in other Activities

   ```
   String getTag = DemoActivity.Tag;
   ```